# Should not we close this question?

Tags: discussion

[Spelling of noun for "absorbing" or "absorption"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/724/noun-for-absorbing)

This question is a lazy question from the OP. He did not do any research on his own. The problem can easily be solved by using a dictionary. Absorbtion is a common error and it is not present in a dictionary. So if he tried, he could get the answer himself. Hence I suggest this question should be closed in no time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, yes. But the author made it clear that his source material was not clear (or possibly mistaken) on the matter. So it isn't a dictionary question, per se.

The problem was when the user said *"I read some articles,"* nobody inquired where those articles were. By looking at the source material, the community could have cited the error cleared up the confusion. But I suspect there wasn't any such material. In that case, you could simply refer them to a dictionary and politely close it as off topic.

Comment: I think if it had been asked on ELU I might endorse keeping it open (someone might produce an explanation of exactly *why* "absorption" doesn't follow the normal derivation pattern). But given this is English Language *Learners*, it seems to me there's nothing really to add to the only existing answer, so it might as well be closed.

Comment: I concur with FumbleFingers. And, I think FF should add this as an answer. The OP did *some* research, but could have done more. No matter, the question was quite adequately answered in one go. Closure is appropriate.